# html div outside of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that should contain a header. Inside it has 3 divs (logo, title, and login) but the last one always is placed outside of the header.

Adding the `HTML` and the relevant `CSS` for reference :

```css
header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  background-color: #00227b;
  padding: 1%;
}

.main {
  background: #ffffff
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0% 5%;
}

.titulo {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 1% 25%;
  width: 600px;
  /*float: left;*/
}

.login {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  /*float: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="header_container clearfix">
  <div class=logo><img width=100 height=100 src="img/logo.png" style="object-fit: cover"></div>
  <div class=titulo>
    <h1>Nombre del sitio</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=login>
    <form>
      <label for="fname">Nombre de usuario</label><br>
      <input type="text"><br>
      <label for="fname">Contrasena</label><br>
      <input type="password"><br>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here it is an image as example:

[image]

Can someone point what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of mistakes in your code, but for summary, you define width for your elements, your title has 600px absolute value. Which is pushing your login button to down. Your title div takes more space than it should. I just copied your code to my editor, delete a lot of your styles. What you wanna do is actually something like this;

Remove all your css that you showed, and put this code. It will give you want you want.

```
.header_container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0%;
  height: auto;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  background-color: #00227b;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

What it does is making items flex, so you can change their position dynamically. Let's say you want to add 1 more item, it's gonna shape accordingly.

Also you should define `display: flex;` before doing `align-item:center;`

I also want to share what I did to your code for reference;

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use these codes with `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around`

```css
.header_container {
    height         : auto;
    display        : flex;
    align-items    : center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header_container clearfix">
    <div class="logo">
      <img
        width="100"
        height="100"
        src="img/logo.png"
        style="object-fit: cover"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="titulo"><h1>Nombre del sitio</h1></div>
    <div class="login">
      <form>
        <label for="fname">Nombre de usuario</label><br />
        <input type="text" /><br />
        <label for="fname">Contrasena</label><br />
        <input type="password" /><br />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```